# map filled with junk records

Tags: c++, stl

I'm using map like this:

```
map<int,CUser*> m_mUsers;
```

...

```
for ( i = m_mUsers.begin(); i != m_mUsers.end(); i++ )
{
    if( (*i).second->GetUserID() == pUser->GetUserID() )
        (*i).second->OnDeviceLogout( pUser );
}
```

...

adding to map:

```
m_mUsers[ sd ] = pUser;
```

deleting from map:

```
i = m_mUsers.find( sd );
m_mUsers.erase( i );
```

When I run this, mostly it works as I'd expect. But very rarely, a junk record is left in map, so when i try to iterate through what is expected to be an empty map, I run into junk record, and crash on i->second->GetUserID()... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if `i` is `end`? Also, a problem may be hidden - this `pUser` could damage the element in the map, as it's just a pointer.

Comment: I have a debugging tip for you.  Implement a function that walks the map and validates every node by invoking a simple validation function.  When you remove a node from the map, mark that node as invalid so that your validation function complains.  Then sprinkle that validation function all around your code.  That way you can catch the invalidation sooner and getting a better handle on the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking for `i != m_mUsers.end()`. That is incorrect unless
it is guaranteed that `sd` exists in your case.

```
i = m_mUsers.find( sd );

//You should do the check before erasing
if (i != m_mUsers.end()) {
    m_mUsers.erase( i );
}
```

That should make the code work correctly. By the way, I recommend you use
`std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` for the `mapped_type` of the map.
If you don't have c++11 available, you can try [technical report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) or [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org),
which include smart pointers.
If you just want to have a reference and don't care about managing `CUser`s in the `std::map`,
you can also do this, which implies you are not managing memory for `CUser`s (in c++11 only):

```
//No room for the question: Who is managing CUser memory in this map?
std::map<int, std::reference_wrapper<CUser>> m_mUsers;
```

And if you don't modify users, you can do even this:

```
//Note I added const to CUser
std::map<int, std::reference_wrapper<CUser const>> m_mUsers;
```

Comment: I'm acually on debian(gcc 4.4.5) and it seems too much trouble to upgrade to 4.7 so I'll probably go with boost and easy modify my code to remove usage of raw pointers.. Thank you everyone for input!

Comment: By the way, for gcc 4.4.5, you can use `std::tr1::reference_wrapper` in header file `tr1/utility`. If you are going to port your code to a compiler that doesn't support `std::tr1`, then, you can stick to boost with `boost::reference_wrapper`. You don't need c++11 for any of these. If you want smart pointers `tr1/memory` has `std::tr1::shared_ptr` if that's what you need. No `unique_ptr`, that one is c++11 only. So depending on if you want portability or depend on gcc, you can choose either to use `boost` or `std::tr1`.